# error en vue js al usar un array

Tags: laravel, vue.js

tengo este componente pero no me sale ningun error y no se muestra estoy usando laravel y vue js ¿hay alguna herramienta que puedan recomendarme para vue js?

```
template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <div class="card mb-3 mt-3" v-for="item in list" v-bind:key="item">
                <div class="card-header" v-bind="item.slug" v-text="item.title"></div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    I'm an example component
                </div>
            </div>
            <infinite-loading></infinite-loading>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return{
                list: [],
                page: 0
            }
        },
        methods: {
            infiniteHandler($stado){

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

si quito los datos del array se ve bien

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <div class="card mb-3 mt-3" v-for="item in list" >
                <div class="card-header" v-bind="item.slug" v-text="item.title"></div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    I'm an example component
                </div>
            </div>
            <infinite-loading @infinite="infiniteHandler"></infinite-loading>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return{
                list: [],
                page: 0
            }
        },
        methods: {
            infiniteHandler($stado){
                this.page++;
                let url ='http://sistema.test/api/post?='+this.page;
                axios.get(url).then(response => {
                    let posts = response.data.data
                    if(posts.length){
                        this.list=this.list.concat(posts);
                        $stado.loaded();
                    }else{
                        status.complete();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Supongo que será porque el array list está vacío, o sea que el v-for no va a iterar sobre nada y lo que haya dentro de ese div no se va a mostrar... Probá declararlo así `list: [1,2,3],` y vé que pasa.

Comment: si ya lo habia notado pero se me hace raro que no se muestre el componente si no estoy utilizando el array todavia gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: del tuto que estoy viendo a el si se le muestra y ami no https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1bdXk1ttWo&list=PLhCiuvlix-rSGTvItDLXyGwyjoNz-CnMJ&index=7

Comment: todo el componente no se muestra

Comment: instalaste la app de vue (vue tools) para hacer debug de vue? te fijaste si en la consola tenes algun error?

Comment: haci se llama vue tools? no la encuentro

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools en el readme están los enlaces para las extensiones de chrome y firefox

Comment: igual, no entiendo que parte del componente querrias que se viera, si son solo divs